# How do I print my password in 1 string and display it to the user?

Tags: python

I have created a random password generator and it works but it displays "Here is your randomly generated password" for every character that it outputs. I would like it to put the full password in 1 string and display it to the user. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import random


def password_generator():
    length = int(input("Input length of password: "))

    for n in range(length):
        symbol_number = random.randint(33, 58)
        character = random.randint(65, 123)

        password = chr(symbol_number or character)

        print(f"Here is your randomly generated password \nPassword: {password}")


password_generator()
```

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the or operator? I don't think it is going to do what you expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

One method you could use is to collect each item from the for loop inside a list and then join the list items together as a string before you display them to use user.

```
import random


def password_generator():
    length = int(input("Input length of password: "))

    password = []
    for n in range(length):
        symbol_number = random.randint(33, 58)
        character = random.randint(65, 123)

        password.append(chr(symbol_number or character))

    password = "".join(password)
    print(f"Here is your randomly generated password \nPassword: {password}")


password_generator()
```

What is the intended purpose of the `or` operator? I don't think it is going to do what you expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

> it displays "Here is your randomly generated password" for every character that it outputs.

That's because you have incorrectly indented your last line. It should be outside the for loop, not inside. You can fix it like so:

```py
def password_generator():
    length = int(input("Input length of password: "))
    password = ""
    for n in range(length):
        symbol_number = random.randint(33, 58)
        character = random.randint(65, 123)

        password = password + chr(symbol_number or character)

    print(f"Here is your randomly generated password \nPassword: {password}")
```

Comment: note that string addition is inefficient, better collect as list and join at the end

Comment: @mozway you are right, but that is not the exact issue they had.